# construct third string with help of given two strings

Tags: python, string

Three strings are given `a`, `b`, and `c`. Initially strings `b` and `c` are empty.
we have to make string `c` using following moves:
move1: we can move first character of string `a` and append to string `b` 
or
move2: we can move last character of string `b` and append to string `c`
there would be multiple possible string by following these two rules but we have to return one according to lexical order.

Example:
given: `a = 'dad'`, `b=""` , `c= ""`
one possible approach:

1. get `a[0]` and append to `b`. so strings became: `a = "ad", b = 'd', c=''`
2. `a[0]` to string `b` : `a = 'd', b = 'da', c = ''`
3. `b[-1]` to string `c`  : `a = 'd', b='d', c = 'a'`
4. a[0] to string b :  `a='', b='dd', c ='a'`
5. b[-1] to string c  :   `a='', b='d', c='ad'`
6. b[-1] to string c  :  `a='', b='', c='add'`
   so here `c = 'add'` other answer is also possible but we have to return one which come first in lexicographical order. so `'add'` would be ans to this example.

   can you please help me to achieve this goal?
   my code:

```
class Solution:
    def solve(self, input1: int, input2: str) -> str:
        res = []
        def rec(st1,st2, st3):
            if not st1 and not st2:
                res.append(st3[:])
                return
            
            if st1:
                rec(st1[1:], st2+st[0], st3)
            if st:
                rec(st1, st2[:len(st2)-1], st3+st2[-1])
        rec(input2, "", "")
        res.sort()
        return res[0]
```

Not able to pass the test cases with this code.
Note: This question was asked in Amazon ML summer school test 2022 which was scheduled yesterday 7pm - 8pm(India), I asked this question after completion of test and I'm curious to know answer because my code didn't work properly. I wrote the above code for the question but it passed only 4/10 testcases and also didn't show the error, so I'm confused about working of my code.

Comment: you have some typos in your code. in `if str1:` there is once `st` which isn't defined, same in the next row `if st:`...or at least I think these are typo mistakes.

Comment: and why do you have input1 and input2 as arguments of solve when input1 isn't used at all?

Comment: @Rabinzel it was given in the question, and input1 is length of input2. It can be solved without using input1 because `if len(st3) == input1` will work same as `if not st1 and not st2` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you sort your list of `res` but you don't check if each solution is sorted in lexicographical order.

little changes of your function (and without class):

```
def solve(input2: str) -> str:
    res = []
    def rec(st1, st2, st3):
        if not st1 and not st2:
            res.append(st3[:])
            return

        if st1:
            rec(st1[1:], st2+st1[0], st3)
        if st2:
            rec(st1, st2[:len(st2)-1], st3+st2[-1])
    rec(input2, "", "")
    print(res)
    sorted_res = sorted(res)
    print('sorted_res: ', sorted_res)
    filtered_res = [x for x in res if x == ''.join(sorted(x))]
    print('filtered_res: ', filtered_res)
```

Given the example `solve(num)`, the output is:

```
['mun', 'umn', 'unm', 'nmu', 'num']
sorted_res:  ['mun', 'nmu', 'num', 'umn', 'unm']
filtered_res:  []
```

The line of code `filtered_res = ...` checks each string in the list whether it is in lexicographical order or not.
You would just return `res[0]` which is wrong here, because `mun` is no valid answer. For this word there is no valid answer (because `filtered_res` is an empty list, given your code does follow the rules correctly).